# Can the Monero daemon bind to a UNIX socket?

Tags: monerod

Is there an option to bind monerod to a unix socket?

I know there is rpc-bind-ip but it doesn’t seem to be happy with sockets.

Comment: Perhaps elaborate in a new question on the problem you are facing in regards to "I know there is rpc-bind-ip but it doesn’t seem to be happy with sockets."

Answer (score 1):

No. Currently only TCP/IP sockets are implemented.